# If its required to have an SMPP provider to send to another SMPP provider?

Tags: smpp, jsmpp

GoodDay Masters,

I want to send an SMS through SMPP. If it's required to have an SMPP provider? or SMPP can develop to have an particular Provider that can handle SMS and send to another SMPP provider?

if SMPP required or optional?

Answer (score 1):

To send SMS to an SMPP provider, you really just need an SMPP client.

[Kannel](http://kannel.org) is an open-source, multi-platform SMPP client that is actively maintained.

You can download it [here](http://kannel.org/download.shtml) and their online docs are [here](http://kannel.org/doc.shtml)